# Connection could not be established with host "mailhog:1025": stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mailhog failed:

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am trying to send a message to an email in laravel in production but I am getting the following error. I have tried php artisan config:cache but it didn't work. How can I fix this ?

`Connection could not be established with host "mailhog:1025": stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mailhog failed: Name or service not known  {"userId":4,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Mailer\\Exception\\TransportException(code: 0): Connection could not be established with host \"mailhog:1025\": stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for  mailhog failed: Name or service not known at /var/www/ipbt/v`

The following are my mail setting:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.leet.my
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=sender@leet.my
MAIL_PASSWORD="...."
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=sender@leet.my
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Mymbsa"
```

Comment: Try `grep -R mailhog * | egrep -v storage` to find out where it's being referenced

Answer (score -1):

problem solved. there are changes on the mail setting. need to figure out the fixed setting.

updated, here are the answer :

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=no-reply@mbsa.gov.my
MAIL_PASSWORD="...."
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@mbsa.gov.my
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Mymbsa"
```